# Difference between session_register and $_SESSION[]

Tags: php, session

What is the difference between `session_register()` and `$_SESSION` array ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the manual page for `session_register`:

> This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.

There are differences (e.g., `session_register` accepts names of global variables, automatically starts the session, etc), but I think a sufficient answer is "don't use `session_register`" unless you really want to know the list of caveats for educational purposes.

Just to elaborate on one point that makes `session_register` bad: it relies on global variables (and `register_globals`).

Answer (score 0):

session_register() is kinda old, already deprecated, but as I know it does the same thing.

also all variables that start with $_ are included in $GLOBALS and are called superglobals