# session_register work but $_SESSION does not :/

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between session_register and $_SESSION[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692086/difference-between-session-register-and-session)

this might sound weird but my problem is this:

If user enters valid login details i take the ip address and the id of the user and put into:

```
 $_SESSION['ip']=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

and:

```
$_SESSION['id'];
```

and redirect to the welcome.php where i check if the session is already started :

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])&&!isset($_SESSION['ip'])) {...redirect to error page..}
```

The problem is that if the user enter valid details he is not redirected to welcome.php.

I change $_SESSION['id'] to session_register("id"); and everything work fine.

All this is on my local xampp server.I dont want to use session_register cuz it is deprecated in the newer versions of php, and its not recomended for using.

So please, how can i solve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`session_register` implicitly calls `session_start`, which will make `$_SESSION` work. Explicitly call `session_start` before you access `$_SESSION`.

Answer (score 0):

You should before using start session, call`session_start` function.

Answer (score 0):

I would put the if statement on the login page itself to capture the info right away.